# spark streaming with json file

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to read json data from a folder location through spark streaming.

**I assume my json data is**

{"transactionId":111,"customerId":1,"itemId": 1,"amountPaid": 100}

**I want the output in Spark SQL table as:--**

```
transactionId   customerId  itemId  amountPaid
    111              1         1       100
```

**my code is :**

```
package org.training.spark.streaming
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
import org.training.spark.streaming.sqlstreaming.Persons

object jsonread {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("jsonstreaming")

    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    // Create the context
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(40))
    val lines = ssc.textFileStream("src/main/resources/fileStreaming")
    lines.foreachRDD(rdd=>rdd.foreach(println))

    val words = lines.flatMap(_. split(","))

    words.foreachRDD(rdd=>rdd.foreach(println))
    val sqc = new SQLContext(sc);
    import sqc.implicits._

    words.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      val persons = rdd.map(_.split(":")).map(p => (p(0), p(1))).toDF()

      persons.registerTempTable("data")

      val jsontable = sqc.sql("SELECT * from data")
      jsontable.show
    }
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: What's not working ? What's the result of println and jsontable.show ?

Comment: println result:---                                                                                                                       {"transactionId":111
"customerId":1
"itemId": 1
"amountPaid": 100}

Comment: jsontable.show result:--                                                                                            +----------------+-----+
|              _1|   _2|
+----------------+-----+
|{"transactionId"|  111|
|    "customerId"|    1|
|        "itemId"|    1|
|    "amountPaid"| 100}|
+----------------+-----+

Comment: your comment says, you able to see the output printed in console? right?
are you expecting it to print in certain format?

Answer (score 0):

Json Data:

```
{"transactionId":"111","customerId":"1","itemId": "1","amountPaid": "100"}
```

Pyspark Code to read from above json data:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, LongType, DecimalType,StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window


sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

stream_data = ssc.textFileStream("/filepath/")


def readMyStream(rdd):
  if not rdd.isEmpty():
    df = spark.read.json(rdd)
    print('Started the Process')
    print('Selection of Columns')
    df = df.select('transactionId','customerId','itemId','amountPaid').where(col("transactionId").isNotNull())
    df.show()


stream_data.foreachRDD( lambda rdd: readMyStream(rdd) )
ssc.start()
ssc.stop()
```